# How can I filter 2 entries in lambda function, like a[1] + a[2] == 10?

Tags: python, filter, lambda

I have a list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and I need to filter `a` where `a[m] + a[n] == 10`
in lambda filter or any optimized solution, but not 2 `for` or anything like this, is this possible?

Example of code:

```
b = list(filter(lambda a, y: a + y == 10, a, b))
print(b)
```

Expected output:

```
[[1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7]]
```

Comment: Keep track of the numbers you are looking for while iteration, if you see a 3 remember that if you see a 7 you have a match, etc. do not use filter but a normal loop. Alternatively put the list into a set at the beginning and then if you see a 3 check if a 7 is in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, you just need to `filter` something else than the list of numbers directly.

You need the cartesian product of the list with itself, i.e. all pairs of numbers from the list.

Use `itertools.product` to get the cartesian product.

```
from itertools import product

result = list(filter(lambda p: p[0] + p[1] == 10, product(a, a)))
```

---

This is an inefficient solution for this particular problem, but it was meant as an example for how to use `filter` and `lambda` to process pairs of values from a list.

Comment: Well, this has quadratic complexity and is in no way better than two nested for loops, there are linear solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that only uses one, rather than two, `for` loops. Note that this only counts distinct pairs (i.e. with different values), and the elements must be at separate indices. You shouldn't try to use `product()` filter here, as it has a quadratic running time. (In contrast, this approach runs in expected linear time.):

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
instances = set()
result = []

for entry in a:
    if 10 - entry in instances:
        result.append([min(10 - entry, entry), max(10 - entry, entry)])
    instances.add(entry)
    
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[[4, 6], [3, 7], [2, 8], [1, 9]]
```

(I assume the exclusion of `[4, 6]` was spurious.)

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not important, here is another way to do so using `set()` and `frozenset()`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

data = set()
for num in a:
    if 10 - num != num and 10 - num in a:
        data.add(frozenset((num, 10 - num)))
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{frozenset({8, 2}), frozenset({1, 9}), frozenset({4, 6}), frozenset({3, 7})}
```

---

If desired, the set can then be converted to a list using a list comprehension.

```
data = [[min(mini, maxi), max(mini, maxi)] for mini, maxi in data]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 8], [1, 9], [4, 6], [3, 7]]
```

---

- For each number in the list, we check if its complement to 10 also exists. We also check that it's not twice the same number (i.e. 5).
- If so, we add a frozenset containing the two values. As sets and frozensets are unordered, this avoids duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

following your discussion i came up with another solution not the best one of all, please see the code block :

```
from itertools import product

def t1(a):
    instances = set()
    result = []
    for entry in a:
        if 10 - entry in instances:
            result.append([min(10 - entry, entry), max(10 - entry, entry)])
        instances.add(entry)
    return result
        
def t2(a):
    data = set()
    for num in a:
        if 10 - num != num and 10 - num in a:
            data.add(frozenset((num, 10 - num)))
    return data

def t3(a):
    return list(filter(lambda p: p[0] + p[1] == 10, product(a, a)))

def t4(k):
    tmp = k.pop()
    ll = []
    while len(k) > 1:
        f  = list(filter(lambda x: tmp + x == 10,k))
        ll.append(f + [tmp])
        k.pop(k.index(f[0]))
        if k: tmp = k.pop()
    return ll
```

**Benchmarking : **

```
%timeit t1([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
%timeit t2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
%timeit t3([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
%timeit t4([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

4.3 µs ± 42.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
5.61 µs ± 163 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
18.6 µs ± 1.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
9.38 µs ± 95.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

P.S. For me was a surprise that the *itertools.product* doesn't give much faster solution then the others, but the cartesian product is a big monster and for longer sequences will be even slower then the rest of the solution.